# inputAccessoryView sizing problem on iPhones without physical home button

Tags: swift, uitableview, autolayout, inputaccessoryview

inputAccessoryView's background view is falling under its own textField and profile picture imageView.

It works fine on regular screen iPhones, but on new iPhones with notches it looks like this:

[image]

Here's how it looks animated when keyboard appears: [Transition animation on becomeFirstResponder()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXwOa.jpg)

Here's my tableView in which I'm trying to add accessoryView:

```
import UIKit
import SDWebImage

class CommentsTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    let viewModel = CommentsViewModel()
    
    let postID: String
    let postCaption: String
    let postDate: Date
    let postAuthor: ZoogramUser
    
    var keyboardAccessoryView: CommentAccessoryView = {
        let commentAccessoryView = CommentAccessoryView()
        return commentAccessoryView
    }()
    
    init(post: UserPost) {
        self.postID = post.postID
        self.postCaption = post.caption
        self.postDate = post.postedDate
        self.postAuthor = post.author
        super.init(style: .grouped)
        self.tableView.register(PostCommentsTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: PostCommentsTableViewCell.identifier)
        
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = "Comments"
        
        keyboardAccessoryView.delegate = self
        configureKeyboardAccessoryView()
        viewModel.getComments(for: self.postID) {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        
        tableView.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
        tableView.allowsSelection = false
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    
    override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
        keyboardAccessoryView.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 60).isActive = true
        keyboardAccessoryView.backgroundColor = .systemOrange
        return keyboardAccessoryView
    }
    
    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    
    func configureKeyboardAccessoryView() {
        guard let photoURL = AuthenticationManager.shared.getCurrentUserProfilePhotoURL() else {
            return
        }
        keyboardAccessoryView.userProfilePicture.sd_setImage(with: photoURL)
    }
}
```

And here's code for my CommentAccessoryView which I use to override inputAccessoryView:

```
import UIKit

protocol CommentAccessoryViewProtocol {
    func postButtonTapped(commentText: String)
}

class CommentAccessoryView: UIView {
    
    var delegate: CommentAccessoryViewProtocol?
    
    var userProfilePicture: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.backgroundColor = .secondarySystemBackground
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        return imageView
    }()
    
    var commentTextField: AccessoryViewTextField = {
        let textField = AccessoryViewTextField()
        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textField.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        textField.placeholder = "Enter comment"
        textField.clipsToBounds = true
        textField.layer.borderWidth = 1
        textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.placeholderText.cgColor
        return textField
    }()
    
    var postButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
        button.clipsToBounds = true
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 30/2
        button.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "arrow.up.circle.fill", withConfiguration: UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: 35)), for: .normal)
        button.tintColor = .systemBlue
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapPostButton), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupConstraints()
        backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        commentTextField.rightView = postButton
        commentTextField.rightViewMode = .always
        autoresizingMask = .flexibleHeight
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        setViewCornerRadius()
    }
    
    func setViewCornerRadius() {
        userProfilePicture.layer.cornerRadius = userProfilePicture.frame.height / 2
        commentTextField.layer.cornerRadius = commentTextField.frame.height / 2
    }
    func setupConstraints() {
        self.addSubviews(userProfilePicture, commentTextField)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            userProfilePicture.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
            userProfilePicture.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerYAnchor),
            userProfilePicture.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
            userProfilePicture.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
            
            commentTextField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: userProfilePicture.trailingAnchor, constant: 10),
            commentTextField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: userProfilePicture.centerYAnchor),
            commentTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
            commentTextField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
            
        ])
    }
    
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize.zero
    }
    
    @objc func didTapPostButton() {
        guard let text = commentTextField.text else {
            return
        }
        commentTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        delegate?.postButtonTapped(commentText: text)
    }
}
```

I've spent days trying to google a fix for that but nothing helps.

There were posts saying they were able to fix something similar by setting customView's bottom constraint to a safe area with the following method:

```
        override func didMoveToWindow() {
            if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                if let window = window {
                    let bottomAnchor = bottomAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToSystemSpacingBelow: window.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, multiplier: 1.0)
                    bottomAnchor.isActive = true
                }
            }
        }
```

But when I use it, AutoLayout starts complaining.

**UPDATE**: I did what HangarRash recommended, changed CommentAccessoryView from `UIView` to `UIInputView` and centering `profileImageView` and `textField` to view itself and not to safe area. Now it's a little bit better, but seems to ignore safe area, `inputAccessoryView` should be above Home indicator but lies beneath it instead. Looking at last cell in `TableView` and Scroll indicator, it seems like `TableView` also isn't aware of `inputAccessoryView` and goes under it.

[image]

Comment: The problem has to do with centering the text field and image view on the safe area center. Devices with a physical button have no safe area so the safe area is the same as the full view. On newer devices the safe area stops well above the bottom of the view.

Comment: Also, you should change `class CommentAccessoryView: UIView {` to `class CommentAccessoryView: UIInputView {`.

Comment: @HangarRash I updated the post, can you please check it? It's a little bit better but inputAccessoryView seems to ignore safe area and lies beneath home indicator (bottom bar)

Comment: I didn't actually say to change the text field to be centered on the main view. I simply pointed out why you were having an issue when centering on the safe area. :) I'm not sure what the best solution is. Maybe you could make the height of the accessory view to be 60 + safe area bottom height. Then go back to centering on the safe area.

Comment: @HangarRash so if I'm going to make accessory view height to be 60 + safe area bottom height, it means that when keyboard slides up the accessory view on top of it will be huge because it's now taking into account bottom safe area height. So I need to figure out a way to animate accessory view height change?